# What is the meaning of the Trinity in Catholicism?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion

In Mertons *Seven Storey Mountain*, his auto-biography from a man of the world to Trappist monk, he goes over in brief the notion of the Trinity in Catholicism in the penultimate chapter for the baptism of a novice:

> So I just said that the Father was the Father and the Son was the Fathers idea of Himself and the Holy Ghost was the love of the Father for the Son; and these Three were One nature, and that nevertheless they were Three Persons - and they dwelt within us by faith.

How correct is this as a brief description? And what is meant by a Person? And in what sense are they One nature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a specific religion alone and thus belongs on [christianity.se].

Comment: @Keelan: I agree it could belong there; but I don't see why it's off-topic here: after all should a question on moral philosophy then cut across the three main schools - deontology, utilitarianism and consequentialism? I was in a bit of a hurry, and not did I want to offend anyone to point out just how close the above characterisation is to Pythagoranism - the One and the Dyad in Platos explication; and also it makes clearer to me in what sense Christianity is understood to be a monotheism.

Comment: Having said that I think you're right that I'll get better answers there than here.

Comment: How does one migrate the question?

Comment: I agree that this question, while not necessarily off-topic here, would be a much better fit on the Christianity SE.  I think, however, that only an official moderator can actually move it.

Comment: You can flag it for moderator attention with a custom message.

Comment: @sunami: I should know how to do that - but I don't; I've checked the tabs above on the page, but I can't see it; perhaps they don't expose this functionality on an iPhone?

Comment: I disagree - the scholastics wrote a lot about natures and persons with regard to God! It should definitely stay here, and I will provide references!

Comment: One reason I didn't post this on Christianity.SE is that I'm not a Christian - but this doesn't mean I'm not interested in the concepts by which Christian debates with itself; a more *anthropological* view might have taken the *Trinity* as an admixture of Roman polytheism with the monotheism of Judaism

Comment: @iphigenie: ok, I'll leave it here

Comment: @MoziburUllah FYI. At Chrisitanity.SE [we are not Christians](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/193/5440). Feel free to ask questions there. This particular question has been asked and answered several times.

Comment: @crownjewel82: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: cf. [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/50205/1787) to the Christianity.SE question "[Philosophical proofs that God must be triune?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/4354/2014)" (That question was closed, too…)

Comment: @geremia: I see you were asking a philosophical question in Christianity and I was asking a Christian theological question on philosophy! People ought to be less severe with questions that cut across subject boundaries.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Yes, so the question is suspended in "limbo"…